# Adding a point to the left of an mtext() in R

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if I could insert a `points()` to appear to the left of an `mtext()`? **In other words**, is there a way I can get the **x, y** of the `mtext()` so I can determine the right place for this `points()` to appear?

**Here is my R code:**

```
curve(dnorm(x),-3,3)
mtext(bquote(paste("Medium: ",bold('CT'[12])," = ", .(round(1/3,3)))),line=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It becomes pretty easy if you use `text` instead of `mtext` as you can use `x` and `y` for both text and points.

```
#Plot the curve
curve(dnorm(x),-3,3)

#Enable drawing outside the plot region
par(xpd = TRUE)

#STEP 3. Add text at certain x and y.
text(x = 0, y = 0.45, 
    bquote(paste("Medium: ",bold('CT'[12])," = ", .(round(1/3,3)))))

#Determine the width of the text you added  
text_width = strwidth( bquote(paste("Medium: ",bold('CT'[12])," = ", .(round(1/3,3)))) )

#Find out x poistion just left of the text.
#Since the text is centre aligned by default,
#you can subtract half the text_width to the x value
#that you had used to add text in STEP 3
#You may also add 10% extra space
points_x = (0 - text_width/2) - (0.1*text_width)

#Add a point just to the left of the text
points(x = points_x, y = 0.45, pch = 20, cex = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Clever to just switch to `text`